# ALAssetRepresentation fullScreenImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, alasset

I have a ALAssetRepresentation question. There is a table which displays gallery images in high resolution. The fullScreenImage method takes too much time and the table works slowly. How can I implement a faster loading? For example, gallery images loading occurs immediately in the https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/print-studio-print-photos/id601882801?mt=8, how could they have done this?

```
  ALAsset *result = photos[_index];

UIImageView *photoView = (UIImageView*)[contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_VIEW];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    ALAssetRepresentation *represintation = [result defaultRepresentation];
    NSURL* aURL = represintation.url;

    [library assetForURL:aURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){

        UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:0.3 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        copyOfOriginalImage = [copyOfOriginalImage imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [photoView setImage:newImg];
            [photoView setNeedsDisplay];
        });


    }
            failureBlock:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can preload images before they are scrolled onto screen. The images you are preloading can be done on a background thread and saved into an `NSCache` instance. The cache will automatically purge (if you set the `countLimit` or the device runs low on memory) so when you preload, check for an item in the cache and load on a background thread if required.